# Passing data between nested #each block in Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

This is how my template looks

```
<Template name="launcherBody">
{{#each workspace in Workspace}}
    <h1>
        Workspace: {{workspace.title}}
    </h1>
    {{#each board in Boards}}
        <div class="board">
            <h2>
                {{board.title}}
            </h2>   
        </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

and here are the helpers

```
Template.launcherBody.helpers({
  workspace: function () {
      return Workspace.find({ "member_id": Meteor.userId()});
  },
  boards: function () {
    /*return Board.find({"workspaceId": ??? }) */
  }
});
```

So as you can see a Board is mapped with Workspace, and to find the Board the need to get the workspace._id from the previous #each.

How can I acheive this??

I have tried Template.parentData() by keeping both Board and Workspace code in different Template, but things are not solving the problemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the parent data context with `Template.parentData(n)` [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)

```
boards: function () {
  var wId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
  return Board.find({"workspaceId": wId})
}
```

Alternatively you could explicitly pass the variable in as an argument to the helper:

```
{{#each board _id}}
```

In that expression `_id` would come from the parent

Then your helper would use that arg directly:

```
boards: function (wId) {
  return Board.find({"workspaceId": wId})
}
```